# Compatibility between v4 and v5 of d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, versioning

I am going to start learning the d3 and I have only a v4 tutorial available, so I am wondering if I will be able to use my learnings of v4 in v5 or it is vastly different.

Comment: Other than d3v5 using promises for d3.json/d3.csv/d3.tsv/etc  (`d3.json("file").then(function(data) {...` as opposed to v4's `d3.json("file",function(error,data) { ...`) there are only minor changes for the most part. Accounting for that change, *most* d3v4 tutorials should still be relevant. The changes that cause code to break when moving from d3v3 to d3v4 are much greater in number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

D3 uses the [semantic versioning](https://semver.org) convention. Therefore, for a given D3 version, like `5.15.1` for instance, you have three numbers: the first one is the *major* version, the second one is the *minor* version and the last one is the *patch* version. Still according to [semver.org](https://semver.org), one has to increment...

> 1. MAJOR version when you make incompatible API changes,
> 2. MINOR version when you add functionality in a backwards compatible manner, and
> 3. PATCH version when you make backwards compatible bug fixes.

Thus, we don't count only the *number* of changes for determining if a given code will work in a given version. For instance, D3 v5.8 introduced way more new features (compared to D3 v5.7) than v5 did compared to v4. Code written for D3 v5.8 may break when referencing D3 v5.7. So, why wasn't D3 v5.8 considered a new major version? Because **all** code written for D3 v5.7 or earlier will work referencing D3 v5.8. All those D3 v5.8 changes happened in a *"backwards compatible manner"*.

The same cannot be said when comparing D3 v4 with v5: **some** code will break (but not all, more on that below). These are the main methods/mini-libraries (and properties) that won't work:

- d3-request (`d3.csv`, `d3.json`, `d3.tsv` etc...)
- `d3.queue`
- colour arrays like `d3.schemeCategory20` etc...

If your D3 v4 code doesn't use any of those, you can use it referencing D3 v5.